# Bound operator norm of a matrix under columns under the image of positive definite maps

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $P_1, \dots, P_n$ are symmetric positive semidefinite matrices. Suppose $X$ is a matrix with columns $x_1, \dots, x_n$:
$$
X = \left[x_1 \mid x_2 \mid \cdots \mid x_n\right].
$$

Consider the matrix
$$
Y = \left[P_1 x_1 \mid P_2x_2 \mid \cdots \mid P_nx_n\right]
$$
Can we provide a bound on the operator norm of $Y$ in terms of $\lambda := \max_i \lambda_{\rm max}(P_i)$ and $\|X\|$?

Comment: Clearly if $P_1 = \cdots = P_n$, then the bound $\lambda \|X\|$ holds.

Comment: Are those real or complex matrices?

Comment: Do you allow your bound to also depend on $n$?

Comment: I allow the bound to depend on $n$ if we can show an example where that is necessary.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn real for simplicity.